# A subclass type as parameter type in superclass constructor java

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, subclass, superclass

So I have a node class and I haven't learned Linked List yet, so I can't use that. To construct a node object I want the parameters to be like this:

```
Node(int numberOfNode, type complex or simpel)
```

I have two subclasses of node called `Simpelnode` and `complexNode` and so a node object can be either one of them. What do I need to do so that the parameter can be of both types?

Comment: Looks like you need multiple inheritance!

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance in Java as far as I know. (It can probably be simulated somehow.) Anyway why would he need multiple inheritance for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node(int numberOfNode, Node node)
```

Since `SimpleNode` and `ComplexNode` are both subclasses of `Node`, a `SimpleNode` *is a* `Node`, and a `ComplexNode` *is a* `Node`. So using `Node` as the argument type will allow passing a `SimpleNode` as well as a `ComplexNode`.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody, I am still learning interfaces so that's why I'm going to try this, I'm more familiar with this ^__^.

Answer (score 3):

Use Inheritance

```
public interface Node{
    //...
}

public class SimpleNode implements Node{
    //...
}

public class ComplexNode implements Node{
    //...
}
```

Then, you can add a `Constructor` like that:

```
public class SimpleNode implements Node{
    public SimpleNode(int numberOfNode){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question. He already uses inheritance, and is asking what the type of the second parameter of the Node constructor should be.

Comment: You cannot get the type from the constructor, you should use inheritance to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `Simpelnode` and `complexNode` and make them extend from Node.

that way you can do:

```
Node n = new Simpelnode();
```

or

```
Node n = new complexNode();
```

also you should read on [java inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and to understand what it means

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your question..

Make a Node interface with constructor

`Node(int numberOfNode,Object o)`  or `Node(int numberOfNode,Node o)`

Make two classes implement it SimpleNode and ComplexNode

as follows `SimpleNode(int numberOfNode,SimpleNode o)`  and `ComplexNode(int numberOfNode,ComplexNode o)`